# networkmanager-strongswan vpn - IKEv2 routing issue

Tags: linux-mint, networkmanager, vpn, strongswan

Until today, my VPN connection to my company was working out of the box using networkmanager-strongswan.

But today (on linux mint 20.1 with kernel 5.8.0-38), I can establish connection to the VPN host, but I can't access any of remote services (web, git, rdp...). Pinging remote IP is also not working.

I have read a bunch of articles and tutorials on internet, and tried a lot of stupid things, but I did not manage to solve my issue: that's why I'm asking help now.

The only thing that worked was using charon-cmd like this:

```
sudo charon-cmd --cert <path_to_cert> --host <host_ip> --identity <identity>
```

But I see this solution as a workaround since I like using NetworkManager as GUI method to connect/disconnect and by using this solution I'm loosing access to my LAN services.

I'm really not good at network configuration, but as far as I understand, that may be a routing issue bacause charon-cmd defines route-based connection while ipsec and networkmanager uses policies. I also noticed charon-cmd uses ipsec0 device while neither ipsec nor networkmanager does.

Here are added policies when connection to VPN is on using networkmanager:

```
src 10.x.x.x/32 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    dir out priority 383615 
    tmpl src 192.168.1.55 dst <host_ip>
        proto esp spi 0xc4ec728f reqid 14 mode tunnel
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 10.x.x.x/32 
    dir fwd priority 383615 
    tmpl src <host_ip> dst 192.168.1.55
        proto esp reqid 14 mode tunnel
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 10.x.x.x/32 
    dir in priority 383615 
    tmpl src <host_ip> dst 192.168.1.55
        proto esp reqid 14 mode tunnel
```

Here is iptable-save output:

```
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [58835:28708461]
:INPUT ACCEPT [58835:28708461]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [55809:6989866]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [55985:7014824]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [306:39378]
:INPUT ACCEPT [5:2408]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1193:105475]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1119:99608]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [12:1454]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [8:916]
:LIBVIRT_FWI - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWO - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWX - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_INP - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_OUT - [0:0]
:ufw-after-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-after-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-input - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-output - [0:0]
:ufw-track-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-track-input - [0:0]
:ufw-track-output - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j LIBVIRT_INP
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWX
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWI
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWO
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
-A OUTPUT -j LIBVIRT_OUT
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWX -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Thanks!

---

edit:

Routes (table 220) WITHOUT VPN

```
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto static src 192.168.1.55 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto static src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

Routes (table 220) WITH VPN via NetworkManager

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0 proto static src 10.x.x.x 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto static src 192.168.1.55 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto static src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

Routes (table 220) WITH VPN via charon-cmd

```
default dev ipsec0 proto static src 10.x.x.x 
<host_ip> via 192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0 proto static src 192.168.1.55 
192.168.1.0/24 dev ipsec0 proto static src 192.168.1.55 
192.168.122.0/24 dev ipsec0 proto static src 192.168.122.1
```

Note: charon-cmd is defining a ipsec0 device while NetworkManager only creates a virtual ip address.

Comment: You mentioned that it worked before, was that on a different system? Are routes installed in table 220 (check with `ip route list table 220`)? Also note that `charon-cmd` does not behave differently by default, if it does, it's because the configuration makes it so (e.g. because the _kernel-libipsec_ plugin was enabled and installed by default but has been disabled explicitly for the other daemons - actually, the NM backend does never load that plugin automatically).

Comment: Thanks @ecdsa for your answer!
I have edited my question to add route infos.
It worked before on the same computer, I tried to figure out what changed: few packages updates via Linux Mint update manager.
Do you know how can I inspect those configurations differencies? As mentionned, `charon-cmd` defines an ipsec0 device while NM is not for exemple.

Comment: Looks fine. It should make your host use the 10.x.x.x address for all traffic except for the two local subnets (these routes and corresponding policies are installed by the _bypass-lan_ plugin), so it matches the IPsec policies (try `ip -x xfrm state` and `policy` for usage stats). There is a possible problem with DNS resolution (due to systemd-resolved), see [this issue for a workaround](https://wiki.strongswan.org/issues/3615). But that shouldn't prevent you from connecting directly via remote IP. So not sure what the problem could be, in particular if it worked before on the same system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer again. `ip` seems to have no "-x" option, and `ip xfrm state` retuns nothing when connected using `charon-cmd`. `systemd-resolved` service is not running. According to the issue you mentionned, there exists a "dummy tun device", and I suspect `charon-cmd` using it while NM is not. Any idea how I can try NM to use the ipsec0 device instead of virtual IP?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, should have been `ip -s ...` to get the stats. Try to check that when the VPN is established via NM. And yes, you see nothing there if charon-cmd uses _kernel-libipsec_ as the kernel is not involved in processing IPsec then. You could try to load that plugin in charon-nm, but I'm not sure how well that works. The dummy TUN device I mentioned in the issue has nothing to do with that plugin or with how charon-cmd behaves, it is a patch for charon-nm itself so that systemd-resolved can associate DNS servers with a device. It doesn't change how IPsec is processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved my issue by serendipity! :)

This week end I was not at home, and tried to look at stats as suggested by @ecdsa (thanks!). It appears that when I connected to the VPN using NM, it was working. I conclued that my issue was not a configuration issue but rather an ISP issue.

After searching a bit, I found out that my french ISP "Free" is sharing one ip v4 to 4 customers (by splitting ports range in 4 sub-ranges). The solution was to ask my IPS to give me a "full stack ipv4".

**Sources:**

- https://dev.freebox.fr/bugs/task/33846
- https://dev.freebox.fr/bugs/task/31957
- https://www.geeek.org/tunnel-vpn-iphone-android-freebox-181/

**French keywords for search engines:**
Problème de connexion VPN IKEv2 strongswan avec Network Manager - Free freebox

Comment: So, when the problem appeared, had you changed your ISP on that exact day, or the ISP had done something on their own? I am having the similar problem but I can't verify, because my ISP and my mobile Internet provider are the same company. :)

Comment: I don't remember exactly how long did it take. I asked for full stack ipv4 via my ISP customer web page, maybe I waited few hours or a day, and then I rebooted my ISP box and it was working.